# Is it possible for Facebook Ads to track iOS app installs without using IDFA?

Tags: ios, facebook, ads, idfa

Apple has introduced new policy, restricting kids category apps from collecting IDFA. We can't integrate facebook sdk in our app, they're rejecting any build that contains SDK which makes use of IDFA.

So we're unable to run Facebook app install ads now, for our Kids category apps/games.
Is there any way to run facebook ads for app installs without using IDFA?

Maybe something like facebook pixel, or attribution of some other kind?

Answer (score -1):

I removed my app completely from AppStore and Again uploaded same app With different bundle Id but this time **uncheck** '**Made for Kids**'checkbox.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to keep it in kids category and want to show Ads without using IDFA Integrate
'AdMob + Kidoz mediation' refer
[1]: https://kidoz.net

This framework you can use. It does't contain 'IDFA'.